# Query value in sub-document dictionary MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following document:

```
"_id" : 19,
"name" : "Elizabeth Moore",
"achronym" : "EM19",
"calc" : {
    "20" : {
        "role" : 20,
        "score" : 15,
        "inRole" : false,
        "range" : {
            "int" : 80,
            "min" : 20
        }
```

and I need to retrieve all _ids having "calc.inRole" false.

I tried:

```
db.coll.find({'calc.$.inRole': false})
db.coll.find({'calc.inRole': false})
```

but none of these worked.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `calc` has fields with unknown keys you need to run [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to transofrm it into array of keys and values. Then you can run [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/index.html) on that array. If you want to have it as single pipeline step you can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) operator to define temporary variable:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            $expr:{ 
                $let: {
                    vars: {
                        arr: { $objectToArray: "$calc" }
                    },
                    in: {
                        $in: [ false, "$$arr.v.inRole" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SGAOEvWcoDS)